# Questions I'd expect to show up in my Interesting category not showing

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, interesting-page

On Stack Overflow, my Interesting category seems pretty accurate but I've noticed a few discrepancies from what I would expect. For example, among my favorite tags is javascript, but I noticed when browsing around that some questions that appear in the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag aren't appearing in my Interesting category, nor are they highlighted with the tan background. For example, a question tagged with 'javascript' and 'forms' doesn't show up in my Interesting feed even though I don't have forms as an ignored tag. Am I misunderstanding how the Interesting category works? Apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: Could you link to some examples of questions that are/are not? I suspect that there is more to it than a single matching tag.

Comment: This is a link to a question not in my Interesting category with the tags 'javascript' and 'forms': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022402/clear-form-fields-on-inactivity. Figured this was a good, basic example to start with.

Comment: That one might not be there just because it's been a few minutes (about 20) since it was last updated, and/or only one of its tags is high in your tag score history. The 'Interesting' page states on it's link that it takes from your subscribed tags and your tag history. Refreshing that page a few times seems to suggest there is also an element of randomness to it.

Comment: Just a quick follow up, this is a link to a question that both shows up in my Interesting category and has the tan background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023461/jquery-simplemodal-can-not-bind-to-onshow. The tags are 'jquery' and 'simplemodal'. jQuery is one of my favorite tags but simplemodal isn't (and it's not on my ignored list either). So the conditions for this example seem to be similar, yet this topic appears on my list of Interesting questions while I don't visit the jQuery category any more frequently than I do the JavaScript one.

Comment: Yup; In that case, what might have been enough to put it over the top is that your `jquery` score is higher than your `javascript` score; (40 in jquery, 28 in javascript). So even though you've favorited both tags, it's putting a higher weight on `jquery` questions due to your score. **Note**: Of course, I'm just speculating!

Comment: Interesting (if that is true about the scoring). Wish there was a way to tweak that by adding weight to certain tags manually. Thanks for the insight.